# ¿Cómo saber en qué posición de un diccionario está un elemento para sacar su valor?

Tags: python, diccionarios

Eso pues, tengo este arreglo; por ejemplo:

```py
a = {'27': '44.200', '16': '10.800', '19': '10.000', '23': '0.000', '21': '1042.400', '15': '9.400', '31': '10.800', '22': '0.000', 
'25': '119.000', '20': '767.200', '28': '0.000', '14': '91.000', '17': '13.200', '29': '0.000', '26': '0.000', '30': '0.000', '24': '119.000', '18': '81.000', '13': '10.800'}
```

Y mi código busca dentro de ese arreglo cierto elemento, por ejemplo `'13'` y lo encuentra. Ahora, lo que necesito es sacar su valor respectivo, que en este caso es `10.800`, lo que con un ejemplo base en la consola sería así:

```py
>>> a = {1 : 30, 2: 40}
>>> a[1]
30
>>> a[2]
40
```

La cosa que me falta es que el código deba hallar la posicion del elemento encontrado, basicamente, hacer la inversa de lo que esta arriba, pero con el elemento que esta antes de `:`.

Comment: El método `items()` del diccionario te puede ayudar

Comment: No existe el concepto de "posición" o índice en los diccionarios, a menos que sea un `OrderedDict`.

Comment: @Christian puedes darme un ejemplo de como usarlo porfas?

Comment: ahora estoy escribiendo la respuesta, espera un momento >_<

Comment: Los diccionarios no se accesan por posición, si no por llave.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho eso cambió en alguna versión de Python, no se cual, donde los diccionarios garantizan el orden de inserción.

Comment: @DanteS, es cierto, si mal no recuerdo la 3.8, también esto hace rato lo permite el OrderedDict, pero conceptualemente un diccionario no tiene una índice posicional, de hecho lo pasa a tener cuando tratas al diccionario como si fuera una lista. De hecho, diciendo esto me desdigo de mi comentario anterior, y la idea que vale es "No existe el concepto de "posición" o índice en los diccionarios"

Comment: @David E. Luna M. por que editaste mi pregunta, aparte de los errores de ortografia, que no importan?

Comment: Hola, @Juan. Las ediciones son necesarias y la ortografía y gramática son fundamentales en este sitio y son bien vistas por la comunidad. Te invito a leer este [artículo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) que trata sobre este tema. Por otra parte, también puedes sugerir ediciones o cuando tengas una reputación superior a 2000 puedes editar directamente las publicaciones de otros usuarios.

Answer (score 1):

Cabe aclarar que un diccionario **no tiene posiciones**, tiene claves (o *keys*). Haciendo un simple ciclo `for` sobre los items del diccionario podemos resolver tu problema. Pero aquí hay un problema, primero recordemos la sintaxis de un diccionario `{k:v, k2:v2, ...}` El diccionario se compone de una clave y de un valor, La clave es única e irrepetible, por el contrario, el valor puede ser cualquiera y se puede repetir. Si tu quieres obtener la clave de acuerdo a un valor, lo más probable es que obtengamos más de un resultado y no un solo valor, como obtenemos al hacer `dict[k]`.

El método `items()` de un diccionario nos devuelve una lista con los valores de las claves y valores en forma de tupla `[(k,v), (k2,v2), ...]` Por lo que podemos usarlo para buscar el valor y luego obtener la clave.

```py
#aquí guardaremos los resultados
results = []

for k,v in a.items(): #iteramos en los items
    if v == "10.800": #verificamos que el valor sea 10.800
        results.append(k) #agregamos la clave a la lista

print(results)
```

**Resultado**

```
['16', '31', '13']
```

Como dije, íbamos a obtener varios resultados. EL resultado que obtenemos es la clave del diccionario, si hacemos `print(a['16'])` obtendremos `10.800` y lo mismo con los otros elementos.

En el ciclo `for` habrás visto esto `for k,v ...` Como dije, el método `items()` nos devuelve 2 valores `(key, value)` por lo que en el ciclo `for` utilizamos 2 variables para obtener los valores por separado donde `k` corresponde a la *key* y `v` al *value*

Esto también lo podemos simplificar a una *list comprehension* (comprensión de lista):

```py
results = [k for k,v in a.items() if v == "10.800"]
print(results)
```

Teniendo el mismo resultado

```
['16', '31', '13']
```

recordemos que solo estamos guardando las claves que coincidan con el criterio, también puedes guardar la tupla de valores `[(k,v) for k,v in a.items() if v == "10.800"]`

Answer (score 0):

Hola buenas si para sacar el valor de una clave en tu código lo puedes hacer mediante
diccionario.get(clave)

```
print(a.get('13'))
```

También puedes hacerlo a traves de diccionario[clave]

```
print(a['13'])
```

Para buscar a lo largo del diccionario lo hacemos con un for y luego si esta la clave sacamos su valor.

```
a = {'27': '44.200', '16': '10.800', '19': '10.000', '23': '0.000', 
'21': '1042.400', '15': '9.400', '31': '10.800', '22': '0.000', 
'25': '119.000', '20': '767.200', '28': '0.000', '14': '91.000', '17': 
'13.200', '29': '0.000', '26': '0.000', '30': '0.000', '24': '119.000', 
'18': '81.000', '13': '10.800'}

for key in a:
if key=='13':
  print(a.get(key))
```